filter to find and replace pattern in .tex before rendering to PDF in quarto
I'm experiencing an issue with Quarto and PDF output. Specifically, I have a very long enumerate list inside a callout box. The problem is that this list doesn’t allow for a page break, causing the list to extend beyond the visible area instead.
After investigating, I discovered this issue is due to the minipage environment within the callout box setup. Each callout box uses two minipage environments—one for the header and another for the body. By removing the second minipage like this:
\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 5.5mm}

(my items, don’t remove these)

\end{minipage}

everything renders perfectly.
The ideal solution would be to create a Lua filter that removes both \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth - 5.5mm} and the corresponding \end{minipage}.
I've tried writing a Lua filter for this purpose; see https://github.com/produnis/minimal_examples/tree/longlist for a minimal example.
However, my script isn’t working as expected. It doesn’t locate the target expressions, so nothing gets removed. Does anyone have insights into where the issue in my script might lie?
This is my script:
local in_calloutlonglist = false

function Div(el)
  if el.classes:includes("calloutlonglist") then
    in_calloutlonglist = true
    local processed_content = {}
    for _, elem in ipairs(el.content) do
      table.insert(processed_content, elem:walk({
        RawBlock = function(raw_el)
          if raw_el.format == 'latex' then
            local start_pattern = "\\begin%{minipage%}%[t%]%{\\textwidth - 5.5mm%}"
            local end_pattern = "\\end%{minipage%}"
            raw_el.text = raw_el.text:gsub(start_pattern, "")
            raw_el.text = raw_el.text:gsub(end_pattern, "")
          end
          return raw_el
        end
      }))
    end
    in_calloutlonglist = false
    return pandoc.Div(processed_content, el.attr)
  end
end


I think I might have an idea why my code is not working.
Lua filters only change Pandoc's AST representation of your document, i.e. before it is then converted to LaTeX. A Raw block filter will not act on Pandoc's LaTeX output, but only on Raw LaTeX blocks that are in the markdown itself.
So, my idea was to write a custom Lua writer. The writer would use pandoc.write to generate Pandoc's own LaTeX output (body only) and modify it with regular expressions or Lua patterns.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do this... ;/

Your analysis is correct. Unfortunately, a pandoc writer won't solve this, because callout blocks are a Quarto feature that pandoc isn't aware of. One would have to write a "custom Quarto writer", but there is no interface to do this. I'm afraid you'll have to export to LaTeX and then edit and compile it "by hand" each time. A possible fix could be to use the adjustwidth environment instead of a minipage, but that will need to be changed in Quarto.
